# Autocomplete textbox with two dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one dropdown for country, another dropdown for cities and an autocomplete textbox for places.

When I select country in the first dropdown it shows cities list for that particular country in the second dropdown.

Next I want to show the places list under the selected city in the autocomplete textbox.

I have one local JSON file, html page and JavaScript file. The HTML code goes as follows:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.9" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json4update.js">
            < script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "js/textauto.js" >
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <select ng-model="Countryselected" ng-options=" coun.country for coun in country" ng-change="getCity()">
                <option value="">Select</option>
            </select>
            <select ng-model="cityselect" ng-options=" c.name  for c in Citydetails " ng-disabled="!Countryselected">
                <option value="">Select</option>
            </select>
            <input id="tags" ng-model="placeselected" ng-keyup="complete()" placeholder="Type place name" ng-disabled="!cityselect" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here goes my .js file, here is the problem I guess. I am not able to use JS function on required place.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("file2update.json").success(function (data) {
        $scope.country = data.records;
        $scope.getCity = function () {
            $scope.Citydetails = $scope.Countryselected.cities;
            $scope.places = $scope.cityselect.place;
        }
    });
    $scope.complete = function ()
    {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: $scope.placeselected
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my JSON file .

```
 {
     "records": [{
         "cities": [{
             "name": "patna",
                 "place": [
                 "p1",
                 "p2",
                 "p3"]
         }, {
             "name": "delhi",
                 "place": [
                 "d1",
                 "d2"]
         }],
             "country": "india"
     }, {
         "cities": [{
             "name": "Australia1",
                 "place": [
                 "A1",
                 "A2",
                 "A3"]
         }, {
             "name": "Australia2",
                 "place": [
                 "a11",
                 "a22",
                 "a33"]
         }],
             "country": "Australia"

     }]
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the time to format your code. There are tools that can help you with this like http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: Always format code properly while posting and remove any unnecessary empty lines as they improve readability and avoid having to scroll through. Make use of Stack Snippets wherever possible as it has a "Tidy" button to auto correct formatting. There is no need to add library/language names in the title because they are already part of the tags.